# How to get a String value from web.config in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I want to get a logFilePath value which I gave by hardcode in to appSettings. I am trying to reach the key value by

```
System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig1 = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement customSetting = rootWebConfig1.AppSettings.Settings["azureLogUrl"];
string pathValue =  customSetting.Value;
```

but I am getting **null reference exception** .
How can I get the value from web.config file?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use:

```
string pathValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azureLogUrl"];
```

You do not need to cast this to string and check for nulls because documentation states:

> Values read from the appSettings element of the Web.config file are
>   always of type String. If the specified key does not exist in the
>   Web.config file, no error occurs. Instead, an empty string is
>   returned.

Comment: need to add using System.Configuration;

Answer (score 5):

You can get the value from web.config like this :

```
string pathValue = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azureLogUrl"].ToString();
```